# Button caption is not displaying DatagridView

Tags: vb.net

I am working in a vb.net application.I've placed a button within the DatagridView control .Button caption is not displaying in DatagridView.Following properties are set to the button
Text as Browse
UseColumnTextForButtonValue as True

Answer (score 5):

i got the answer .Set the Null value of the button same as the Text property of the button

Answer (score 1):

just change the grid view button column "useColumntextforbutton"  property to true it will show Your Text on Button